# How to stop fullcalendar from interrupting dragging and resizing when polled

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I have been trying to get fullcalendar to react to polling for new events, but whenever it calls refetchEvents, if I am dragging or resizing something, it stops me, as if I have released the mouse at the position I am in, which moves or resizes the event respectively to the wrong spot.

I have a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6v71u297/1/), to show this in action.

Here is the code, if it helps:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  /* initialize the calendar
  -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    editable: true,
    events: [{
      title: 'event1',
      start: '2017-01-26T08:00:00',
    end: '2017-01-26T10:00:00'
    }, {
      title: 'event2',
      start: '2017-01-05',
      end: '2017-01-07'
    }, {
      title: 'event3',
      start: '2017-01-09T06:30:00',
    end: '2017-01-09T09:30:00',
    }]
  });
});
setInterval(function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
  console.log('refetchEvents called');
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be not the most efficient, using `fetchEventsLock` reference on `eventDragStart` and `eventDragStop` and fetch events only when released `=== false`.

```
var fetchEventsLock = false;
$(document).ready(function () {

    /* initialize the calendar
    -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

    function toggleLock() {
        fetchEventsLock = !fetchEventsLock;
        console.log('Set To ' + fetchEventsLock)
    }
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({        
        eventDragStart: toggleLock,
        eventDragStop: toggleLock,
        /* Other option removed */

    });
});
setInterval(function () { 
    if (fetchEventsLock === false) {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
        console.log('refetchEvents called');
    }
}, 5000);
```

Comment: That works well enough for me, other than it needs eventResizeStart: toggleLock and eventResizeStop: toggleLock as well.